# r: find lowest value matching criteria over columns

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this

```
personID t1 t2 t3
1         0 11 0
1         0 11 0
2         0 11 13
2         0 11 13
3         0 0  0
3         0 0  0
```

I need to make sure that each person has one test score above 10. If they do not, they have to be removed from the data frame. I also want to keep track of the lowest score above 10, and add it to a new column.

Thus, the result would look like this:

```
personID     t1 t2 t3 new
   1         0 11 0   11
   1         0 11 0   11
   2         0 11 13  11
   2         0 11 13  11
```

Comment: See `?do.call` and `?pmin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was to go the `data.table` route, I think you could do it with a melt and join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[
  melt(dat, id.vars="personID")[value > 10, .(new=min(value)), by=personID],
  on="personID"
]

#   personID t1 t2 t3 new
#1:        1  0 11  0  11
#2:        1  0 11  0  11
#3:        2  0 11 13  11
#4:        2  0 11 13  11
```

Comment: I don't know much about data.table but when I do this, I think I have a problem since in my actual data frame I have values other than these test scores and they are going into the new column...could I specify which columns? like dat[2, 5, 8] somewhere?

Comment: @rdk - you can do `melt(dat, id.vars="personID", measure.vars=c("t1","t2","t3"))` for instance.

Comment: I also have columns containing the dates the tests were taken. How would I make a new column, containing the corresponding date to the test I added to the new column?

Answer (score 0):

using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
#convert your data (named DF here) to use data.table syntax
setDT(DF)

DF[ , {
  # vector of row-wise minima within ID
  m = do.call(pmin, .SD)
  # confirm acceptance condition
  if (min(m) > 10)
    # add new column by appending it to current data
    c(.SD, list(new = m))
}, by = personID]
```

Comment: Im not that familiar with data.table and when I set this to a variable or try to find its class is doesn't seem to exist...do you know the problem? Is there a way to set that back to a data frame?