# r: Add lowest value matching criteria and a corresponding observation to new columns

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this

```
ID       score obs
1        0     a
1        11    b
1        12    c
2        1     d
2        11    e
2        2     f
3        0     g
3        0     h
3        0     i
```

I need to make sure each person has a score above 10. If a person has no score above 10, all rows the personID shows up need to be deleted. The lowest score above 10 needs to go to a new column and the corresponding obs needs to go into a new column too (*note: there is not a situation where a person has two of the same score). Result should look like this:

```
ID score obs nScore nObs
1  0     a   11     b
1  11    b   11     b
1  12    c   11     b
2  1     d   11     e
2  11    e   11     e
2  2     f   11     e
```

Ideally, every repeated personID should also be deleted so that the lowest score is kept in the score column. The result looks like this:

```
ID score obs nScore nObs
1  0     a   11     b
2  1     d   11     e
```

I would be happy if you could help me get to the first result. If you could help me get the second result, I don't require that you show me how to get to the first result before getting to the second result (like if you got to the second result all in one step).

Comment: It would be a good idea to link to your previous question that is pretty similar. This may help those trying to answer get some ideas.

Comment: Are `(id, score)` couple unique? I mean, can `(1, 0, "a")` and `(1, 0, "b")` "coexist"?

Comment: in a previous question I made sure there was a score below a certain criteria, and otherwise deleted the person (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683459/r-delete-all-rows-with-same-value)  For this problem, I could do : newdf <- df[ave(df$score, df$ID, FUN = min) >= 10,]. To make sure that I have only people with test scores above 10. However, this is more complicated since I only want to keep the lowest score and the lowest score above 10 (potentially getting rid of scores in the middle and above lowest score above 10), and also keep track of a corresponding value

Comment: @BrunoZamengo No that couldn't happen. Thanks for the good question.

Comment: in a previous question I made, I had a similar problem except instead of looking for criteria over rows, I was looking for criteria over columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685201/r-find-lowest-value-matching-criteria-over-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `dplyr`

```
#Q1 
DF1=DF%>%group_by(ID)%>%mutate(nScore=min(score[score>10]))%>%filter(!is.infinite(nScore))%>%mutate(nObs=obs[score==nScore])


# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID score   obs nScore  nObs
  <int> <int> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0     a     11     b
2     1    11     b     11     b
3     1    12     c     11     b
4     2     1     d     11     e
5     2    11     e     11     e
6     2     2     f     11     e

#Q2
DF1%>%group_by(ID)%>%slice(which.min(score))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID score   obs nScore  nObs
  <int> <int> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0     a     11     b
2     2     1     d     11     e
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `d`, using [`aggregate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/aggregate), [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) and [`subset`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/subset)

```
# get lowest score greater than 10 per id
lowest10 = aggregate(score~ID, subset(d, score>10), FUN=min);
lowest10 = merge(lowest10, d, by=c("ID", "score"));
names(lowest10) = c("ID", "nScore", "n0bs");

# get lowest score per id
lowest = aggregate(score~ID, subset(d, ID%in%lowest10$ID), FUN=min);
lowest = merge(lowest, d, by=c("ID", "score"));

# merge the informations
newD = merge(lowest, lowest10, by="ID");
```